# Bootstrap: responsive image alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a code like below - columns with full-width images.

```
<div class="col-3">
    <img src="..." class="w-100" />
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
```

As images can be of different size, it's not guaranteed that content below images will be displayed in one line (image's height is supposed to differ, depending on image's width).

In other words, when an image within `.col` is 200 px width, should be 200 px height, etc. (width = height).

Comment: in other words you have to get the width value and set height?

Comment: Yes, yet via JS I get an original image's dimensions rather than of its container

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 with css:

```css
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.img-prev {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-prev img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538356913997-b04286765811?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=39e83600a508d87be2ea636e02f30f95&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538333785596-1cc0b5e03551?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c942fc493dad02801a99aa191414a535&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538379585867-44bf200a3d25?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=29782178fb2019f60bee12c2fcfacff4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538367735494-5e6cc0ff555a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3066861f0cf81849de20853676dee717&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example 2 html:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538356913997-b04286765811?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=39e83600a508d87be2ea636e02f30f95&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" height="200" width="150">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538333785596-1cc0b5e03551?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c942fc493dad02801a99aa191414a535&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" height="200" width="150">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538379585867-44bf200a3d25?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=29782178fb2019f60bee12c2fcfacff4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" height="200" width="150">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538367735494-5e6cc0ff555a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3066861f0cf81849de20853676dee717&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="" height="200" width="150">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example 3 with jq:

```js
var imgs = $('.img-prev>img');
imgs.each(function(){
  var item = $(this).closest('.img-prev');
  item.css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + $(this).attr('src') + ')', 
    'background-position': 'center center',            
    '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
    'background-size': 'cover', 
  });
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
.img-prev {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row img-list">
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538356913997-b04286765811?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=39e83600a508d87be2ea636e02f30f95&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538333785596-1cc0b5e03551?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=c942fc493dad02801a99aa191414a535&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538379585867-44bf200a3d25?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=29782178fb2019f60bee12c2fcfacff4&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-4 mb-2">
        <div class="img-prev">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538367735494-5e6cc0ff555a?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=3066861f0cf81849de20853676dee717&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this one,

```
<div class="container">           
  <img src="loginBackground.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Cinque Terre" width="200" height="200"> 
</div>
```